# Question about lipschistzian functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

could somenone tell me how to prove if these functions are locally (in x) or globally lipschitzian?

a)$f(t,x)=|t|(|tx|)^{1/2}$
b)$f(t,x)=(\frac{1+t}{1+x})^{1/2}$ with $t,x\in]-1,1[$

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if $f(t,x)$ is Lipschitz in $x$ for every fixed $t,$ or if $f$ is Lipschitz as a two variable function on $(-1,1)\times (0,1)?$

Answer (score 0):

Hints: a) Consider $f(1/2,x) - f(1/2,0).$

b) Lipschitz functions on bounded domains are bounded. Is $f$ bounded on this domain?